# How to mock a Doctrine Repository in Zend Framework 3 using PHPUnit

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpunit, zend-framework3

I am trying to test a ZF3 controller action which, in the process, selects a user from the database via a Doctrine ORM repository using a token given as a GET-Parameter. As I need to make sure that the User exists I need to create a mock of the repository returning the user object. How do I do this?

My setup is the following:

The class UserControllerFactory is instantiating a UserController class:

```
class UserControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface {

/**
 * @param ContainerInterface $container Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager
 * @param string             $requestedName
 * @param array|NULL         $options
 *
 * @return UserController
 */
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, Array $options = NULL) {
    $entityManager         = $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
    $userRepository        = $entityManager->getRepository('User\Entity\User');

    return new UserController($container, $entityManager, $userRepository);
}}
```

In the UserController the acton resetPassword is called. It gets the needed parameter from the route and selects a user from the database matching the token:

public function resetPasswordAction() {
        $request  = $this->getRequest();

```
    $passwordResetToken = $this->params()->fromRoute('token');
    if(strlen(trim($passwordResetToken))) {
        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(
            [
                'passwordResetToken' => $passwordResetToken
            ]
        );
...
```

If no user is found. The action will redirect to user to a different action.

PHPUnit test case:

```
public function testResetPasswordActionCanBeAccessed() {
    $passwordResetToken = 'testToken1234';

    $this->dispatch("/user/resetPassword/$passwordResetToken", 'GET');
    $this->assertNotRedirect();
}
```

As there is no user having the token is will be redirected.

To my knowledge I need to create a mock of the repository (userRepository), create a mock user and use the mock repository retrieve the mock user having the token.

I am not sure if this is the right approche as I tried a lot of tutorial and never got it to work. I don't know how to "replace" the, in the action called "userRepository" with the in the unit test created mock object.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

---

**EDIT**

As suggested by @DonCallisto (thank you) I changed my test case code to:

```
    ...
    $mockedEm = $this->createMock(EntityManager::class);
    $mockedUserRepository = $this->createMock('Core\Repository\EntityRepository');
    $mockedEm->method('getRepository')->willReturn($mockedUserRepository);
    $mockedUserRepository->method('findOneBy')->willReturn($mockedUser);

    $this->dispatch("/$this->_lang/user/resetPassword/$passwordResetToken", 'GET');
    ...
```

but after calling the "dispatch" in the test case my controller call

```
$user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(...)
```

will still return NULL instead of the mocked user object given in the test. If I debug the $mockedUserRepository, my $mockedUser is assigned correctly.

I also tried the suggested:

```
$mockedUserRepository->findOneBy([arrayWithParams])->willReturn($mockedUser);
```

But this will through an error due to the fact that $mockedUserRepository->findOneBy() is returning NULL.

Comment: I've answered a similar question seconds ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176036/how-to-mock-entitymanager-for-phpunit